# How to turn a string into an object reference?

Tags: java, string, object-reference

Just as a precurser to the question, I am moderately new to Java, so please bear with me.

I am right now attempting to create an account system, and it seems that automating the account ID process is more difficult than previously thought. I want to be able to have customized user IDs for each individual object reference, so it's easy to access, count how many users there are, edit values in the object, etc.

I basically want:

> int accountsMade=1;
>
> userAccount (A1) = new userAccount(other Input);

And then the next time a user registers an account, the object reference will be:

> userAccount (A2) = new userAccount(Different input);

Is there any way to automate this system? It seems as if there is, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you're looking for a "Map" such as the `HashMap` class.  This allows you to create an object and then store the reference to the object in the Map with an associated name value.  Later one can come back and use the name to look up the object in the Map.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do is create and keep reference to a HashMap object. These are key-value pairs, in which providing a key (in this case, the user ID provided by the user) allows you to get the value (in this case, the user account object) in a very quick and efficient fashion.

The actual signature of the HashMap you'd want to use would be Map.

Here's the current documentation on HashMap: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html.

However, I think there's a pretty significant issue with the design you're building right now, and that's that you're constructing a new userAccount object each time you get input. The concept of an account suggests some sort of continuity - saved data, passwords, etc. Right? GMail doesn't make a new account for you every time you sign in.

So, you're going to need somewhere to keep that data, somehow. You could either use an external database, like SQL, or, if you're 100% sure that your use cases and userbase will never, ever, change, you could just hardcode account objects into your prototype and check user login attempts against the keys in the HashMap. Either way, I'm not sure it'll work for your purposes to be constructing a userAccount object upon user login.